# facebook api : getting user name/picture without prompting the user to login/authenticate right away

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Some sites these days (yelp??) show the users picture, name and ask the user to invite more friends or login using facebook. Only when the user clicks on login the user gets the window "xyz app is requesting following info, do you want to authenticate...."

so how do they do that? basically get facebook user's name and picture without prompting him/her to login right away. I know you can use graph api and as long as u have the fb user id, u can access their public info: name picture etc. But how do you get fb uid at all without asking the user to authenticate/grant permissions right away?

please shed some light on this.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is called [**Instant Personalization**](http://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/):

> Just as your News Feed on Facebook is built uniquely for you, instant
> personalization sites let you easily bring your friends and interests
> with you.
>
> Partners adhere to Facebook's guidelines and may only use
> your public information to serve you a personalized experience. Public
> information includes your name, profile picture, gender, networks, and
> other information you've made public.
>
> When you first arrive on a
> participating site, you will see a notification and a way to turn off
> the customized experience in one click. Your information can only be
> used to present you with a more personalized experience and cannot be
> transferred to advertisers or used for any other purposes.

You need to become a partner to Facebook to have this privilege :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can display the user's image without asking him to auth your app by keepign the following <img> tag, the only thing is that he has to be logged into Facebook.

```
<img src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=anyAccessToken'/>
```

Now the anyAccessToken could be **any access token** - it could be even your own one, just any valid token and it will do the trick :)

Hope it helps.